# C# enum query linq and general type?

Tags: c#, linq, enums

So I want to know that, from my enum value list, how many specific enum value exists.

So I wrote like

```
public int GetNumFromList(List<Elements> list, Elements eType)
{        
    IEnumerable<Elements> query = //list.Where(p => p.GetType() == eType);
        from listchild in list
        where listchild == eType
        select listchild;
    /*
    Debug.Log("Cur check type is " + eType + " and now selected number is " + query.Count());
    if(query.Count() > 0)
        Debug.Log(" and query 0 value is "+ query.ToArray().GetValue(0) + " type is "+ query.ToArray().GetValue(0).GetType());
        */
    return query.Count();
}
  public enum Elements{Fire, Water, Wood, Metal, Earth, None}
```

So this works well, but can I make this more shorter and neat?

```
//list.Where(p => p.GetType() == eType);  This part doesn't worked.
```

And how can make this for generic type, T?

Comment: What is `p.GetType() == eType` supposed to do? `eType` is not a type.

Comment: @Rob yes so that part is error. so I make it // comment

Comment: Why have you tried to call `GetType()` in method syntax, but not in query expression syntax?

Comment: @JonSkeet I didn't know well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > how can I make it for T general type? not only for [Elements] enum.

```
public int GetNumFromList<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, T eType)
     where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible

{
    return list.Count(x => x.Equals(eType));
}
```

The problem is that there is no explicit way to say "T must be an enum". Requiring T to be a value type, and implement IComparable, IFormattable, and IConvertible, eliminates many (but not all) non-enum types.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for enums and value types

```
public int GetNumFromList<T>(List<T> list, T item)
{
    return list.Count(x => x.Equals(item));           
}
```

Comment: It's okay, but it requires to override `Equals` method for every class type to be used here, right?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
IEnumerable<Elements> query = list.Where(p => p == eType);
```

Comment: Thanks. And this is another question, how can I make it for T general type? not only for [Elements] enum.

Comment: What you mean general type? It can be generic but only for specific type: class or enumeration etc, but not for all of them together

Comment: So like public int GetNumFromList<T>(List<T> list, T eType)

Comment: fubo answer is very good it will work for enums and value types out of the box, but for classes, you need to remember to override the `Equals` and `GetHashcode` methods for the classes you want to use with this generic method.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as short as this:

```
public int GetNumFromList(List<Elements> list, Elements eType)
{
  return list.Count(x => x == eType);
}
```

The generic version:

```
public int GetNumFromList<T>(List<T> list, T eType)
{
  return list.Count(x => x.Equals(eType));
}
```

Notice your classes should override `Equals` method in the generic case.

Comment: Thanks. And this is another question, how can I make it for T general type? not only for [Elements] enum.